# how to change log level in runtime when use boost log

Tags: c++, boost-log

In my program, at the moment I'm using boost :: log to write the log. If, like log4cxx, I want to dynamically update the log output level by modifying the configuration at runtime, what should I do? Another problem is that the output log level is 1,2,3 such figures, not info, debug such a string, do not know how to solve，thank you all，here is my code：

```
    BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(lg, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt< >)

    int init_logger(const std::string& file_name_of_cfg) {
        if (file_name_of_cfg.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "FAILURE: Filename of config for logger is empty." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        try
        {
            // Open the file
            std::ifstream file_of_cfg(file_name_of_cfg);
            if (!file_of_cfg.is_open())
            {
                std::cerr << "FAILURE: Could not open " << file_name_of_cfg  << " file" << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }

            // Read the file_of_cfg and initialize logging library
            boost::log::init_from_stream(file_of_cfg);

            // Add some attributes
            boost::log::add_common_attributes();

            return 0;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "FAILURE: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

here is my setting:

```
    [Core]
    Filter="%Severity% >= 1"                                   


    [Sinks.1]
    Filter="%Severity% >= 1"                                   
    Destination=Console                                        
    AutoFlush=true                                             
    Format="[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] <%Severity%> %Message%" 
    Asynchronous=false                                         

    [Sinks.2]
    Filter="%Severity% >= 2"                                   
    Destination=TextFile                                       
    AutoFlush=true                                             
    Format="[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] <%Severity%> %Message%" 
    Asynchronous=false                                         

    Target="logs"                                              
    FileName="logs/cple.logger.%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%a.%5N.log"       
    RotationTimePoint="00:00:00"                               
    RotationSize=104857600                                     
    MinFreeSpace=4294967296
```

Comment: Have you read the Boost.Log documentation to find out what it can do? It contains a wealth of information on the various kinds of sinks available, and on how to define your own.

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Log does not provide API for updating configuration from file. The closest you can do is to remove all sinks and then re-read the config file, which will create and add new sinks to the core.

```
boost::log::core::get()->remove_all_sinks();
boost::log::init_from_stream(file_of_cfg);
```

You don't need to touch your loggers or attributes as those are not managed by the config file. Note, though, that since this operation is not atomic, you may miss a few log records that are emitted while there are no sinks registered in the core.

A more correct solution would be to avoid directly initializing the logging library from settings and interpret the config file yourself. You can read the settings file by calling [`parse_settings`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/parse_settings.html) and then iterate through the settings container to create and initialize sinks. [Filter and formatter parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.filter_formatter) from the library can be used to initialize filters and formatters. You would save shared pointers to the sinks in your data structure before registering in the core. When you need to update the configuration, you can simply read the config file and update the sinks through the pointers you saved. The exact way how you discover that you need to update the configuration is specific to how your application interacts with the user.

> Another problem is that the output log level is 1,2,3 such figures, not info, debug such a string

If you want to use string representations of your enums in the filters in the config file then you should register [a filter factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.adding_support_for_user_defined_types_to_the_filter_parser) for your enum type. That factory should be able to parse enum values from strings. Similarly, if you want to see strings for enum values in the log files, you should register [a formatter factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.adding_support_for_user_defined_types_to_the_formatter_parser).